# Elsevier cas-dc class hyperref warning: ignoring empty anchor on input line

Tags: hyperref, warnings, els-cas

I'm trying to compile the Elsevier CAS double column template which is provided at:

```
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip
```

When I compile with pdfLatex on Overleaf, I get the following warning with respect to the `\maketitle` call

`Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 15.`

What is the reason for this warning and how can it be fixed?

Below is a highly reduced version of the template .tex file `cas-dc-template.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\shorttitle{Silly Walks}  
\shortauthors{Smith et~al.}
\title[ mode = title ] {Silly Walks and their Place in Modern Society}
\author{Steve Johnson}
\ead{steve@silly-walks.com}
\author{John Stevenson}
\ead{john@silly-walks.com}
\address{Ministry of Silly Walks, High Pressure Silly Walk Testing Facility, London, England}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
This is the intro with ref \cite{Fortunato2010} and \cite{NewmanGirvan2004} and \cite{Vehlowetal2013}.
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}
\bibliography{cas-refs}
\end{document}
```

The full CAS template is also available as a ready-to-go Overleaf template here:

```
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-double-column-template/hhzpymgjmxfk
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the compilation possible and the warning disappear I made two thing:

1-  I put the directory `thumbnails/`  that comes with the distribution (.zip), *but is not installed!,* in the same directory of the LaTeX document.

2-  In the file `cas-dc.cls` I moved the package `hyperref` to the end of the file, after `geometry`.

```
%
% Page geometry
%
\usepackage[%
   paperwidth=210mm,
   paperheight=280mm,
   vmargin={19.5mm,18.2mm},
   hmargin={18.1mm,18.1mm},
   headsep=12pt,
   footskip=12pt,
   columnsep=18pt
]{geometry}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\colorlet{scolor}{black}
\colorlet{hscolor}{DarkSlateGrey}
\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle={\csuse{__short_title:}},
  pdfauthor={\csuse{__short_authors:}},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX3; cas-sc.cls; hyperref.sty},
  pdfproducer={pdfTeX;},
  linkcolor={hscolor},
  urlcolor={hscolor},
  citecolor={hscolor},
  filecolor={hscolor},
  menucolor={hscolor},
 }

\endinput
  
%
% End of class 'cas-sc'
%
```

Then I got the Silly Walks including the email icon. (I also commented the lines after Introduction).

[image: out2]

This a comparison of the logs after and before the changes.

[image: logi]

So this is the fix. It seems that the reason for the warning is that the class does not follow the recommendation to load `hyperref` as the last package.

Comment: worked like a charm, and was very simple. thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could report the issue to Elsevier. "Bugs, feature requests, suggestions and
comments may be mailed to elsarticle@stmdocs.in"

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. The answer is clear and solve the problem. Congratulations and thank you for the help.

Comment: I am still not able to run it, could you please share the files directly?